# Как сохранить неизменный id при сохранении объектов моделей в разных функциях?

Tags: python, django, model, queryset

Проблема следующая: у Юзера есть четыре параметра (пин, который присваивается рандомно; возраст, который он указывает; сообщение, которое он вводит и кол-во вопросов, которое он выбирает). Все это 4 разных функции (должно быть по вопросу на странице). Как мне получить всю эту информацию в одном запросе (каждый раз при вызове следующей функции, естественно меняется `id` и создается новый объект, содержащий новый параметр, например, `pin`, но потеряв старый, полученный из предыдущей функций, например, сообщение). При этом юзер регистрацию проходить не должен. А назначенный `id`, который является `primary_key`, я не знаю. Есть ли какой-то выход из ситуации? Заранее спасибо!

`Views.py`

```py
def info(request):
    return render(request, 'info.html')

    def age(request):
    return render(request, 'age.html')

def quant(request):
    c = Age()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        b = request.POST.get('age')
        c.age = b
        c.save()
        a = Age.objects.values()
    return render(request, 'quant.html', {'a': a})


def message(request):
    c = Age()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        b = request.POST.get('quantity_text')
        c.quantity = b
        c.save()
        a = Age.objects.values()
    return render(request, 'message.html', {'a': a})
```

`Models.py`

```py
class Age(models.Model):
    age =  models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pin = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.age, self.pin, self.messsage, self.quantity
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Почему каждый раз вы создаете новые объекты, если, судя по всему, вы пытаетесь изменить какую-то информацию. При таком подходе база данных будет пухнуть от мертвых данных. Не понятно назначение модели. Почему Возраст содержит пины, сообщения и какое-то количество? Расскажите подробнее, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Есть подозрение, что вы все делаете неверно

Comment: @cauf да, Вы правы, я именно этого и пытаюсь избежать, но не знаю как сделать правильно. Есть модель User(в данном примере она называется Age), который указывает возраст, количество вопросов, которое ему будет показано, секретное сообщение, и ему назначается пин. Все это должно быть в одном объекте. Но проблема в том, что все это назначается в разных функциях, поэтому у меня создается такое количество объектов. Не знаю как это уложить все в один объект.

Comment: Вообще весь смысл в том, что User  создает этот объект для будущего игрока. Игрок вводит переданный ему пин, и, соотвественно, получает нужное кол-во вопросов (которое содержится в объекте), получает сообщение, переданное ему игроком.

Answer (score 0):

Если, фактически, у тебя объект должен создаться только после того как пользователь введет все вопросы, ты создай одну страницу в которой ее части будут скрыты(не показаны пользователю) и после ввода первого поля, скрывай часть где оно вводится, показывай часть для ввода второго и так далее.
Либо если тебе прям надо через перезагрузку страницы что бы все отдавала именно джанга, то можешь передавать это значение в следующий view и с помощью `input type="hidden"` проведи его через всю цепочку форм.
Ну или после каждой формы записывай значение в request.session и после того как введешь все, собери их и создай в итоге один объект

Comment: Огромное спасибо, пронесла с помощью hidden, все получилось! Просто супер благодарность)